# Does use of "pushing up daisies" and "six feet under" in the same sentence make it stylistically or otherwise redundant?

Tags: word-choice

Example: "Young Lensky is pushing up daisies six feet under"

Wouldn't it be the same as saying: "Young Lensky is dead is dead"?

Comment: Imagine how much funnier Monty Python's dead parrot sketch (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Parrot_sketch) would have been if the authors had steered completely clear of metaphors for the word *dead*.  Not much funnier at all I'd warrant.  Sensewise, yes redundant, style-wise not so much.

Comment: I have known people who routinely use the two expressions together, as in "Young Lensky is six feet under, pushing up daisies." It is intended to be humorous, so avoid it unless you are joking about the person's death.

Comment: As @Peter demonstrates if using both together, the order should be six feet under and then pushing up daisies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the intended goal of your writing.

If your goal is to entertain an English-speaking audience with mixed idiomatic expressions, then it's perfectly fine. Cf. High Performance Mark's comment about Monty Python.

If your goal is to informally communicate that Young Lensky is dead, then it is redundant. Your message would be clearer if you select one idiom and use it in an isolated sentence. Pick one:

- Young Lensky is pushing up daisies.
- Young Lensky is six feet under.

Finally, if you are writing in a context that is not informal and not for entertainment purposes, then I would recommend refraining from idioms altogether. At best, they can be seen as unusual and out of context. At worst, they could be seen as offensive.

For example, imagine you are responsible for writing an obituary to be read by the Lensky family. A more appropriate phrasing might be "Young Lemsky passed away early Saturday morning."

Comment: "At worst, they could be seen as offensive." - (I am UK based) - in 1997, the day after Princess Diana was killed, I went to work and (of course) it was the main topic of conversation. We discussed where we had been when we heard the news. One colleague, whose outspokenness I was fond of, said "When I turned on the radio and heard the solemn music, I thought the Queen Mum had carked it". Nervous laughter from some of  those within earshot, genuine amusement from others.

Comment: Ha!! I suppose the norms are different for public figures. And some people just have a way with words, no matter the norms!

Comment: I very recently heard someone ask "Will we get a day off when the Queen pegs out?", which made me (a republican, and no admirer of the royal family) feel a little strange.

Comment: Old joke: teacher: why were you absent yesterday, Johnny? Johnny: Grandpa got burnt, Miss. Teacher: Oh! Not badly, I hope! Johnny: Oh no, Miss, they don't mess about at the crematorium.